# Ultimate Predator

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Jeff is an avid hunter and has documented a food chain made of $n \geq 1$ predators where n is an integer. Every animal has a predator-prey relationship with one another. But the relationship is not transitive--animal $a$ being a predator of animal $b$ and animal $b$ being a predator of animal $c$ does not imply that animal $a$ is a predator of animal $c$.

Jeff states that an animal $x$ is the ultimate predator if for all other animals $y$, either $x$ is a predator of $y$ or $x$ is a predator of some third animal $z$ that is a predator of $y$.

Help Jeff prove that there will always be an "ultimate predator".

**I need advice on how to view this problem, because I currently am completely stuck.**

Comment: Make examples for small $n$ to get a feel for the problem.  Is it true when $n=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: It's not quite right to speak of "the" ultimate predator, since there can be more than one. For example, in the system rock/paper/scissors, all three "species" are ultimate predators.

Comment: Hint: for any animal $a$, let $p(a)$ be the number of other animals that $a$ treats as prey. Prove that if $a$ is such that $p(a)$ is maximal among all the animals, then $a$ is an ultimate predator.